# 还 in 你还好吗 is just for emphasis?

Tags: grammar, simplified-characters

还 in  你还好吗 has the meaning of "still" , "as well", "even", or just for "emphasis (强调)" and no meaning here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> 你好吗? = how are you?

> 你(还好)吗? = are you (still ok)?

You need the 还 in 你还好吗 to indicate you are **still** alright. (nothing bad has happened)

For example, if someone slipped and fell, his friend wouldn't ask him 你好吗? (how are you). His friend would ask 你还好吗? (are you *still* ok)

If you ask a friend 最近生意如何? (How's business?), the typical reply would be

1. 非常好 (extremely good/ very good)
2. 很好 (very good/ good)
3. 还好 (good/ still good = still considered good = modestly good)

You can see '还' in '还好' indicates 'still' or 'modestly'

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**还**， 这里用在形容词前，表示程度上勉强过得去。

如果把这句话改成陈述句， "你还好"，意思就是你的状态应该是可以的，可以刚好到达'好'的标准.

所以, "你还好吗"问的就是"你的状态还算得上好吧"，或者"你的状态还可以吧"。

Comment: 我懂了。非常感谢你的帮助 !  ~